# How to prove that the partial Euler product of primes less than or equal x is bounded from below by log(x)?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

How does one prove $\prod_{p \leq x}(1 - \frac{1}{p})^{-1} \geq \log(x)$?

Comment: That inequality is wrong. Did you mean $\left(1-\frac1p\right)^{-1}$?

Comment: True. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by  Daniel Fischer,
I think you mean

$\prod_{p \leq x}\frac1{1 - \frac{1}{p}} \geq \log(x)
$.

Let $P(x)$ be the set of positive integers
with all of their prime factors
$\le x$.
Every positive integer $\le x$
is obviously in $P(x)$.
Therefore,

$\begin{align}
\prod_{p \leq x}\frac1{1 - \frac{1}{p}}
&=\prod_{p \leq x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac1{p^k}\\
&=\sum_{n \in P(x)} \frac1{n}\\ 
&>\sum_{1 \le n \le x} \frac1{n}\\ 
&> \ln x
\end{align}
$

by one of the usual
harmonic sum bounds.

Note: As in many of my answers,
nothing here is original.