# Bounds on harmonic prime product

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, products, harmonic-numbers

So it is known that
$$
\prod_{p\, \text{prime}}\frac{p}{p-1} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}.
$$

It is also known that for any particular harmonic number $H_n$, that we can bound it by
$$
H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} < \log(n)+1. 
$$

I was wondering if there was any similar bound for the above product of the first $m$ primes, hopefully in terms of some logarithm of $m$
$$
\prod_{k=1}^m\frac{p_k}{p_k-1} < f(m)
$$

Just by performing some plotting in matlab, it appears that $f(m)=2(\log(m)+1)$ works, however I do not know if this (or a tighter bound) has been proven

If anyone could point me along the correct direction, I am having trouble because I cannot seem to find the name of this prime product, so finding resources is tough. Thank you

Comment: Your first line is simply meaningless as both sides diverge. The usual trick is to add an exponent, so that e.g. the right hand side becomes the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: As for your main question, the product $\prod_1^m \frac {p_k}{p_k - 1}$ grows the same speed as the sum $\sum _1^m \frac 1 {p_k}$, and the latter (if I remember correctly) grows as $\log\log m$. I did a quick search and found [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes).

Comment: marty cohen's answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567350/how-to-prove-that-the-partial-euler-product-of-primes-less-than-or-equal-x-is-bo might be of some help (though the bounding inequality there goes in the other direction).

Comment: Third [Mertens' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems), with $\log p_m\asymp\log m$ as $m\to\infty$, implies $$\frac{1}{\log m}\prod_{k=1}^m\frac{p_k}{p_k-1}\underset{m\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}e^\gamma.$$